# Standard notation for the set of children of a node in a rooted tree

Tags: graph-theory, notation, trees

In graph theory, given a rooted tree $T$ and a node $a \in V(T)$, is there a standard way to refer to the set of all children of $a$? I have seen $CHILDREN_T(a)$ being used, but this seem quite clumsy to me, especially when used several times on the same line, e.g. $S = \bigcup_{b \in CHILDREN_T(a)} CHILDREN_T(b)$. In contrast, the common notation for the neighbourhood of $a$ is denoted $N_T(a)$, which is very nice and short. Is there a similar nice/common way to refer to the children of the node $a$ in a rooted tree?

Comment: perhaps, "successor"?

Comment: I am thinking more along the lines of reducing CHILDREN to a single symbol of some sort, or two at most, similar to how N(a) refers to the neighbourhood of a.

Comment: Then, why not just $C(a)$?

Comment: I agree that this looks nice and makes sense. The reason why I have hesitated to use it is, if there is something widely recognised that I (as a non-mathematician) didn't know about, I would prefer to use that. If there is not, then I guess $C(a)$ is as good as anything, certainly much nicer than $CHILDREN(a)$ :)